# using rviz models in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, urdf, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have created a robot model for rviz in urdf format.....how can i use this model on gazebo...i mean what changes do i have to make???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39006/using-rviz-models-in-gazebo/) by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on 2012-07-17**:
thnks @erwan r. it worked :-)

**Comment by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on 2012-07-17**:
but there is only one problem whenever i set static="false" my object runs into a corner of my world

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-07-17**:
Not sure about it but static prevents objects to move (another point of view required). If set to false and your object is colliding another one, force effects will throw your object away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey i found a command that can convert .urdf  files to .model files for gazebo

```
rosrun gazebo urdf2model -f basic.urdf -o basic.model
```

---

Originally posted by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) with karma: 234 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-07-18**:
??? Gazebo provides several tools that you can check [there](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo). I don't know what your application is, but you can use both urdf and models. I don't know if there're equivalent.

**Comment by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on 2012-07-18**:
but in my gazebo i m not able to spawn urdf files my gazebo always crashes

**Comment by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on 2012-07-18**:
so this is better option

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-07-18**:
The final solution is your choice, but maybe you could describe more the problem to understand why spawning urdf files make gazebo crash. Urdf files should spawn as well as models, so maybe there is a bug to be reported or a wrong practice to correct. But that's your choice.

**Comment by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) on 2012-08-10**:
thnk u this troubled one of my collegues for days

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

URDF models can be spawned in Gazebo according this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BasicPR2Controls#Adding_an_STL_Mesh_Object_in_Simulation).

You have to ensure that all required fields in urdf are present (visual but also collision, inertia ...) to be sure that you model will be displayed.

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3